# Parse Data from One Activity to Another

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, hyperlink

I made a couple of autocomplete, datepicker and spinners in a activity and i want to parse data on another activity onclick.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/r"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"></AutoCompleteTextView>

<Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:id="@+id/dButton"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<Spinner
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/c"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/s"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

I want the data from the upper field save into image link like: values from field will be added into a image link which have variables like http://example.com?v=var1&v1=var2&v3=var3

These value will generate a dynamic link. And when we click on a image link it open in a browser.
So, i can do it

Comment: use intent and pass data to the other activity if that is what you meant

Comment: use `putExtra()` and `getExtra()`

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is bit difficult to understand. this is used to pass data between two activities

```
Intent i = new Intent(source.this, destination.class);
i.putExtra("MyData", whateverYouWantToPass);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the destination class do this...

```
String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("MyData");
```

Comment: i want to Image link to get values from field. And when values are taken imageview get these values and make a dynamic link

Comment: Suppose user write its name in a autcompletetext view like : john  and then click on a button. Button takes the user to another activity where there is a imagelink and user toches on it. The value that user typed i.e john is put inside a variable of imagelink i.e http://example.com?name=variable. and we know that variable value is john now. So when user clicks this link opens http://example.com?name=john

Comment: on button click pass values like i shown you ans then use `setText(value_u_get)` for image link.